# Extracting IDA view-A data or Assembly from IDApython

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I'm a newbie in IDApro.

I'd like to save the assembly code or IDA view-A(not a graph view) text through IDApro.

I know the how to save using GUI, but there are so many files i have to change.

So I wanna use python script embedded in IDApro called IDApython.
I had tried to use `gen_file` function, but its not work properly.

for example, I use `gen_file` like this:

```
gen_file(OFILE_ASM, file_name, 0, idc.BADADDR, GENFLG_ASMTYPE)
```

Please let me know what kinds of way i can choose

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in IDA 7.0 and later, and outputs the full `IDA View-A` contents when run from the `Execute Script` pane:

```
path = ida_kernwin.ask_file(1, "*.*", 'Output Filename')
num = gen_file(OFILE_ASM, path, 0, BADADDR, 0)
print("Bytes Written: 0x%x" % num)
```